# Does this idea give an algorithm for constructing Hadamard matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, open-problems, conjectures

[Fedor Petrov's](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4312/fedor-petrov) answer of my [preceding question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/282179/90655) shows that my question reduces to the famous [Hadamard conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix)  about Hadamard matrices of order $4k$. So I decided to study this conjecture and I got the following raw idea of constructing Hadamard matrices:

> If $V_i$ is a row of $H_n$ then add $V_i$ to the $i$th column.
>   For example: Start with
>   $$H_4=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
> 1&1&-1&-1\\
> 1&-1&1&-1\\
> 1&-1&-1&1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   Let $H_{4n-4}$ be a symmetric (*if it exists*?) Hadamard matrix. Then by the above idea we extend this matrix to  $H_{4n}$ as follows:
>   $$H_{4n }=\begin{pmatrix}H_{4n-4}&A_{(4n-4)\times 4}\\
> A^T_{4\times (4n-4)}& B_{4\times 4} \\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   where $B$ is a symmetric  matrix and the first row of $A$ is $(1,1,1,\dots,1)$. Thus
>   $$AA^T=4I_{4n-4},\quad H_{4n-4}A+AB=0,\quad  A^T A+B^2=4n I_4.$$

**Question:** Does this idea give an algorithm for constructing Hadamard matrices?

Any suggestion for improving this idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no symmetric Hadamard matrix of order $12$.

Comment: Are you sure? why?

Comment: http://neilsloane.com/hadamard/

Comment: The question of how large M can be such that 1) M is a Hadamard matrix of order k, and 2) M is a minor of matrix H, and 3) H is a Hadamard matrix of order n leads to 2k being at most n. So your augmentation idea does not produce a Hadamard matrix when M has order of 8 or greater.  I think a book of Wallis may have this result.  Of course, Hadamard product allows n to be 2k.  Gerhard "Augmentation Helps In Determinant Maximizing" Paseman, 2017.09.30.

Comment: Also, it seems your system of matrix equations gets problematic for n larger than 2, as AA^t should have rank at most 4, and can't be the multiple of a large identity matrix.  You might try researching augmentation as an approach to one of Fedor's questions, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/261531 .  Gerhard "Can Provide Some Technical Assistance" Paseman, 2017.09.30.

Comment: Finally, while @Wojowu is correct about their being no order 12 symmetric Hadamard matrix, the link provided is not enough, as there may be a symmetric version of the unique one presented. Trying to make one by hand will convince one otherwise.  Gerhard "Experience Is A Good Teacher" Paseman, 2017.09.30.

Comment: There exist symmetric Hadamard matrices of order 12, though they're not easy to find by hand. See, for example, figure 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.01732.pdf

Comment: If $H$ is Hadamard of order $n$, and $M$ is a minor of $H$ which is Hadamard, then $M$ has order at most $n/2$. For this, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3819.pdf but note that what the authors refer to as Szollosi's theorem is better known as the Jacobi determinant identity.

Comment: How can you have $AA^T=4I_{4n-4}$ if $A$ has rank 4? Don't you mean  $AA^T=4I_{4}$ and later $A^T A+B^2=4n I_{4n-4}$?